# Enable DLL compilation

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, dll

I have a VB.NET Project, and would like to, as with C# Projects, build and have dll files generated and dumped in the Bin/debug folder.

Currently, I have the project configured for ANY CONFIGURATION and ALL CPUS but when I do a build, I still do not have a bin folder or a debug folder containing a DLL. What am I missing here please? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure? By default the bin folder is not shown in the solution explorer, you have to click the "show all files" button to see it.

Comment: Well, when I expand one of the projects, there is instead a Bin/x64 folder. In the others I see no bin folder but instead obj folder instead.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're asking two questions:

1. how do I get the dependency binaries copied to the startup application's bin/debug folder
2. how do I see the bin/debug folder in the solution explorer

For #1, this happens automatically, as long as your startup application has a reference to the other projects.  This is true for VB.NET and C# projects.

For #2, I don't know how to see the bin/debug folder in the solution explorer, but I just right-click on the projects and choose "Open Folder in Windows Explorer".  I've never had it *not* have a bin folder as long as everything compiled properly.